# Concat Avro files using avro-tools

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, avro, avro-tools

Im trying to merge avro files into one big file, the problem is `concat` command does not accept the wildcard

```
hadoop jar avro-tools.jar concat /input/part* /output/bigfile.avro
```

I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does
>   not exist: /input/part*

I tried to use `""` and `''` but no chance.

Comment: where are your input files?

Comment: @54l3d: I think the question was: Are they stored on the local file systems or HDFS ?

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU may be, they are on HDFS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I quickly checked Avro's source code (1.7.7) and it seems that concat does not support glob patterns (basically, they call `FileSystem.open()` on each argument except the last one).

It means that you have to explicitly provide all the filenames as argument. It is cumbersome, but following command should do what you want:

```
IN=$(hadoop fs -ls /input/part* | awk '{printf "%s ", $NF}')
hadoop jar avro-tools.jar concat ${IN} /output/bigfile.avro
```

It would be a nice addition to add support of glob pattern to this command.

Comment: make sure to filter out "Found xxx items" from hadoop fs listing

Comment: @EdiBice Updated the example. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `hadoop jar avro-tools.jar` one can run `java -jar avro-tools.jar`, since you don't need hadoop for this operation.