# Hadoop giving error on avro tools concat

Tags: hadoop, avro

I'm trying to concatenate multiple avro files in an HDFS directory using avro tools. I'm following the approach as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856838/concat-avro-files-using-avro-tools) question. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/myuser/output/output.avro (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Util.fileOrStdout(Util.java:79)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.ConcatTool.run(ConcatTool.java:58)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:80)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

- The directory `/user/myuser/output/` does exist.
- The command I'm using is `hadoop jar /home/myuser/avro-tools-1.7.4.jar concat ${IN}
  /user/myuser/output/output.avro`
- `$IN` has the value `/user/hive/warehouse/somedatabase.db/some_table/on_date=2016-05-01/for_date=2016-05-08/confidence=0.8/000000_0`
- The hadoop version is Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.

Theoretically, it should work, however it does not. I feel as if avro-tools is checking the local filesystem for the file(directory?) and that is causing the error. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Avro 1.7.5 or later or prefix your argument with "hdfs://".

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-867 for more details.

Basically, AVRO-867 rewrote the utility methods used by avro-tools to deal with the file system. They now work as you expect, ie. no longer require the hdfs:// prefix and support any file system.